# javascript rotation translation function

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

Does anyone have a translate function for x/y positions after rotation in javascript?

for instance:

```
this.mousex = event.clientX - this.el.offsetLeft;
this.mousey = event.clientY - this.el.offsetTop;
```

gives me the mouse position however my parent div is rotated by x-degrees which of course means the mousex/mousey are not correct. Does javascript have a function for this built in (not that I've seen one but..)?

thanks very much

Comment: Well, it's got `Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()` and `Math.tan()` to help you out, but the math will have to be done by you.

Comment: dammit, going to have to go brush up on my school trig.. hoped js might have added a simple point translation by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote the following for you, I've checked it with `(1,0,Math.PI/2)` and `(0,1,Math.PI/2)` and it works.

```
function rotatePoints(x,y,angle){
   var point={};
   point.x = x*Math.cos(angle)- y*Math.sin(angle);
   point.y = x*Math.sin(angle) + y*Math.cos(angle);
   return point;
}
```

Should work, see [Rotation Matrix in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)

Of course, angle should be in radians. You can convert degrees to radians by multiplying by `Math.PI` and dividing by 180. The angle is counter clockwise, if you want to rotate clockwise passing -angle or changing sin to -sin should work.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your div is rotated by `t` radians clockwise. Then the transformed coordinates are:

> x' = cos(t)*x - sin(t)*y
>
> y' = sin(t)*x + cos(t)*y